# how can i return node properties and node id together?

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

i added below function to my datalayer.The function returns all publishers, and it works fine.

```
    public IEnumerable<Publisher> GetPublishers()
    {
        var query = client
            .Cypher
            .Match("(p:Publisher)")
            .Return(p => p.As<Publisher>());

        return query.Results;
    }
```

However, i also want to return node IDs too. I couldn't find how to do it? Could you help me?

Below is my Publisher class.

```
public class Publisher
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreateTime { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset UpdateTime { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

}
```

I want node IDs to be assigned to ID property of returning Publisher objects. Is it possible? or how else can i do it?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Don't try and do this. You shouldn't be using the internal node ID for anything. If you need a unique ID, assign your nodes your own surrogate ID (deserializing that will then be trivial).

Comment: i just need an incrementing integer. like in ms sql server... how do you produce yours then? guid looks long..

Comment: If you need a incrementing counter you can mimic it by using a special counter node holding its value as a property: `MERGE (n:Counter {counterName:'myCounter}) ON CREATE SET n.value=0 ON MATCH n.value = n.value +1 RETURN n.value`

Comment: Thank you it's a nice idea. Can i use this id generating query as a subquery in ON CREAT SET Id=... part of a merge query?